# Ability to use KeyVault in Logic Apps for SQL Connectors

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-keyvault

How to access Key Vault secrets in Logic app to provide secured authentication with SQL Connector.? Do we have any possibility to configure the JSON Script of the app?

**Logic App design work flow:**

[image]

I would like to configure ConnectionName, SQL ServerName, SQL database name Values in JSON Script and UserName and Password, I would like to get from KeyVault in JSON Script.

Can any one let me know how should be the JSON Configurations for this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the goal to provide the keyvault secret as the sql connector connection string? or during run time of the logic app you want to retrieve some secret and use it.

If we want get the connection string from key vault during deployment time we can do that using the ARM templates(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/keyvault-support-for-arm-templates/).

If we want to get the secret during run time in secured fashion of logic app one way is to have the secret of the keyvault deployment ( by retrive as explained in the above step as logic app parameter as a secure string and use the logic app parameter run time. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#parameters)

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: Can any one please help on this problem.